# Redirect_to not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

I'm creating a checkbox with Ajax call to update an attribute... everything is working fine but my redirects aren't working as intended (nor flash[:notices])

If i use chrome Network i can see the GET method for the desired page but no redirect whatsoever and flash[:notices] don't work (I'm assuming it's related)

So Here's my code:

**Controller :**

```
def toggle
  @prato = Prato.find(params[:id])

if params[:sugestao] 
  @sugestao = params[:sugestao]
  if @sugestao == "true" and Prato.where("sugestao = ? AND categoria_pratos_id = ?", "1" , @prato.categoria_pratos_id).count <= 2
 @prato.update_attributes(:sugestao => @sugestao)

else

if @sugestao == "true" and Prato.where("sugestao = ? AND categoria_pratos_id = ?", "1" , @prato.categoria_pratos_id).count > 2
  flash[:notice] = "nao"

end
end
if @sugestao == "false"
   @prato.update_attributes(:sugestao => @sugestao)

end
end


if params[:menu]
  if @prato.update_attributes(:menu => params[:menu])


  else

  end
else 
  if params[:ativo]
    if @prato.update_attributes(:ativo => params[:ativo])

  else

  end
end
end
flash[:notice] = "fds"
redirect_to "/pratos/new?"
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= check_box_tag 'Ativo', prato.id , prato.ativo,:class => "task-check2", :id=>"task-check2"  %>
<%= check_box_tag 'Sugestão', prato.id , prato.sugestao,:class => "task-check3", :id => "task-check3"  %>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".task-check2").bind('change', function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: '/pratos/'+this.value+'/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"ativo": this.checked}
    });


});


$(".task-check3").bind('change', function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: '/pratos/'+this.value+'/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"sugestao": this.checked}
    });


});
```

**Routes**

```
resources :pratos do
  member do
    post 'toggle'
  end
end
```

Ok So everything works as intended... Problem is i want to show a message when user activates 3 checkboxes but Flash Notices and redirects aren't working... Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: first.. redirect will make new request on server... so flash will  not work with redirect

Comment: i use flashes with redirects all the time and it works just fine :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the **js request** to controller that's why this is not redirecting and not show your flash message because your page not loaded. For this you have to change your div data using JavaScript on the **success of AJAX** or **toggle.js.erb**

Comment: I kinda understand what you're saying and it makes sense but can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: can you add flash message view

Comment: You can only select 3 dishes